# How to recognize and kill all threads started in R session

Tags: r, pthreads, r-doredis

Sometimes threads are started by R package (e.g. [in doRedis](https://github.com/bwlewis/doRedis/issues/17), see [related code](https://github.com/bwlewis/doRedis/blob/master/src/alive.c)). Is there a way how can I list threads spawned within current R session and kill these threads within R? Or can I recognize and kill them in Windows task list?

I am using Rgui in Windows XP.

Answer (score -2):

In the command prompt window of Windows, try:

```
taskkill /F /IM processname.exe
```

to kill all processes with that name.
If you have multiple processes with a slightly different name, you can use a wildcard:

```
taskkill /F /IM partialname*
```